# How can Java programs in different JVMs affect each other unintendedly?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, interaction

I was running 3 Java applications, each in their own JVM.

Then, all applications froze (at the same time) after about 30 minutes.
When running only one JVM the problem does not occur, and it has proven to be stable for more than 13 hours under heavy load. The problem only occurs when i run multiple JVMs.

Just to clarify, there is no (intended) interaction going on between the programs. Also, the programs use 2 threads each which are working together in a synchronised manner. The applications are identical, just running on different data. Again, they should be completely independent of each other as each program runs on its own JVM.

I am not asking for a specific solution to my problem, but I'm interested in finding out if behaviour like this is usual or not.

And most importantly, if it is a well-known problem, are there any rules-of-thumb on how to avoid problems like this? Are there aspects of multithreading (in my case, each program uses two threads) that are known to cause similar issues?

**+Update**:
First of all, here's the code that is used for wait/notify operations between the threads.

Main thread, only two methods (called in a loop):

```
public void waitCycles(int c) {
    worker.setWaitDuration(c);
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.wait(500);//very unlikely to actually wait 500ms. Should be notified.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
float[] learn(boolean[] values) {
    worker.setLearnValues(values);
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.wait(500);//Same as above
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    float[] out = worker.quality;
    worker.quality = null;
    return out;
}
```

And here is the code from the Worker-Class (extends Thread), also part of a loop:

```
        if (learnValues != null) {
            float[] q = new float[learnValues.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < learnValues.length; i++) {
                q[i] = outs[i].learn(learnValues[i], 1);
            }
            quality = q;
            learnValues = null;
            synchronized (host) {
                host.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        //"waiter" is an integer value that is set by calling "setWaitDuration(int c)"
        if (waiter > 0) {
            waiter--;
            if (waiter <= 0) {
                waiter = -1;
                synchronized (host) {
                    host.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
```

After freezing both threads still consume much processor time, which doesn't make sense since the programs should write textfiles containing information about the current learning progress, but that doesn't happen (despite the fact that both threads still are running).
I've double-checked, there are no infinite while-loops that might cause this.
And it still doesn't make sense why all three programs freeze seemingly at the same time.
I use the JDK8u25 and its built-in JRE on Windows 8. I did not encounter any memory issues.

Comment: How are they synchronized, and what are the programs doing?

Comment: It is a machine learning program, more precisely artificial neural networks. One thread evaluates the quality of the ANN and sends it learning patterns, it also provides several tools to analyze the ANN. The second thread contains the actual ANN and performs all the ANN-specific computations. Both Threads need as much processor time as possible. Synchronization is done in case any Thread performs an action that requires the other Thread to wait. At the end, the sleeping Thread is woken up again. I use mostly Thread.wait(time) and someMonitor.notifyAll()

Comment: What is the state of the system when the three JVMs hang? Are they using CPU at all? Or are they all blocked on something? Are other threads in the JVMs able to make progress? Also, what OS and Java versions? This isn't a well-known problem, so there may be something wrong with your system.

Comment: On the other hand, there may be bugs in your wait/notify code that manifest themselves only when the system is loaded by multiple JVMs. If there is only a single JVM you might just be lucky that it works. In particular, is your wait() call in a loop? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: What does a thread dump of the vms show? Are they threads in wait state? => thread dump on linux/unix can be taken with kill -3 <java_pid>

Comment: I've updated the post to anwer most of your questions.

Comment: In theory, the JVMs should be completely independent with regard to internal things like synchronization, static fields, etc.  But they could affect each other if, for example, they're reading and writing the same files on disk.  Are you doing anything like that?

Comment: I'd be curious to know whether the computation actually gets significantly further into the data in the single-VM 13-hour case or whether it stops at about the same point. I don't like your `wait()` calls. They should always be in a loop controlled by a Boolean which the notifier sets.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede no, the programs do not read/write to the same files. I am sure about that. EJP: The dataset is not that large actually, and the programs get through all of it several times. The "Data" consists of example patterns for the learning algorithm. And thanks for your criticism about the wait() call, i can see why it is better to have it controlled by the notifier. I will correct that.

Comment: Make a copy of your program and then start removing parts one by one. Try and produce a program that's as small and simple as possible and still shows the problem you described.

Comment: I would also ask whether any of these classes extends `Thread.` There's a specific warning against using `wait()` and `notify()` on `Thread` objects in the Javadoc. If you have this problem, make them implement `Runnable` instead, and use `new Thread(Runnable)`.

Comment: @EJP Yes, the Worker class extends Thread. I will correct that tomorrow and see if that was the cause of the problem. I cannot find that warning through google or in the Javadoc. Could you post a link please? I would like to know what kinds of problems it causes.

Comment: Javadoc of [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)): "It is recommended that applications not use `wait, notify,`or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances."

Answer (score 2):

Two things immediately come up to my head:

1. Server memory. By running 3 JVMs simultaneously it could be your server is overloaded and all 3 apps performance degrade significantly
2. External IO such as disk / network. If all your apps depends on disk or network connectivity, and your server ran out of disk space, or network connection drops, then all 3 can have problems simultaneously

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But unfortunately none of these things can be the cause of my problem. Do you know if, and how heavy load can affect timed waiting in Java? The only possible explanation that comes to my mind is that waiting threads are never woken up again, but they should wake up after a specified time anyways. But if that was the case, i would notice that the programs are at least working (even if they are working extremely slowly), yet that is not the case. I cannot see anything in my code that would block a thread forever.

Comment: I must second the memory thing--are you sure it's not anywhere near the top of PHYSICAL memory of the computer (Without swap)?  Multiple JVMs do not play well when you run out of memory they cause each other to swap out and eventually lock up the entire computer... I've seen it many times.  to test it, you might try shutting off all swap space and use a memory tracker (process manager in windows) to ensure that you are not using more than 3/4 of your ram.